# Return from context above

Tags: ruby

This question is little complicated to formulate but I will do my best. Trough our code we have snippets such as

```
response = do_something()
return response unless response.ok?
```

I was think of writing wrapper method which would remove need for this step, and it would look something like this

```
def rr(&block)
  response = yield
  unless response.ok?
    # somehow do return but in context above (magic needed here)
  end
  response
end
```

After that I would be able to minimize code from above to be

```
response = rr { do_something() }
```

Seems impossible but this is `Ruby` so maybe there is a way?

Comment: Apart from the implementation of `rr`, I think you have to call it like: `response = rr { do_something }`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to return across multiple layers of the stack when something goes wrong (which appears to be what you are trying to do) is to raise an exception:

```
class RequestFailedException < StandardError; end

def rr(&block)
  response = yield
  unless response.ok?
    raise RequestFailedException, "Response not okay: #{response.inspect}"
  end
  response
end
```

Usage:

```
def do_lots_of_things()
  rr { do_something }
  rr { do_something_else }
  rr { another_thing }
end

begin
  do_lots_of_things
rescue RequestFailedException => e
  # Handle or ignore error
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to just write a wrapper that does exactly that? Functionally it seems you're just ignoring non-`ok?` responses:

```
def rr
  response = yield

  response.ok? ? response : nil
end
```

Maybe I'm missing something here but I don't see why you'd need to force a `return` in another context, something that's not even possible anyway.

Comment: Implementation is there just as an example, I was hoping for something that would allow me to propagate return to context above. We have hundreds of mentioned snippets in our code, and I was looking for a way to refactor.

Comment: You'll need a different pattern. As Ajedi32 points out, exceptions are one form of flow control you might want to look into.